# Open Broadcaster Software and Shutter only capturing the background (eOS Freya)

Tags: screenshot, gala, display

Ever since I installed elementary OS, I couldn't get Open Broadcaster Software and Shutter working properly.

They only capture the background. When asked Shutter to capture the wingpanel, it captures the background region underneath it.
On the other hand, when asked OBS to use the Xcomposite feature, capturing windows and their subregions works. Again, I can't use full screen capturing in OBS.

**Update:**

- I currently have 2 graphics cards in this computer. <s>It seems, like Ubuntu has chosen the older one as the primary graphics card.</s>
- In Ubuntu's *Software & Updates* > *Additional Drivers* I can choose from:

  1. Using X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati (open source, tested)
  2. Using Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx-updates (proprietary)
  3. Using Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx (proprietary)
- I had selected the `fglrx-updates` driver, which gives me much better performance, but buggy screen capturing. Changing to the open source X.org driver fixes the screen capturing bug in Shutter, but the driver does not seem to have OpenGL support (= no OBS). The performance drops significantly aswell.

`sudo lshw -c video` output (currently using the fglrx driver):

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Curacao XT [Radeon R9 270X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:50 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7e40000-f7e5ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:51 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f7b00000-f7b3ffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f7b40000-f7b5ffff
```

**Update 2:**
I've installed the latest *AMD Catalyst™ 15.7 Proprietary Linux Graphics Driver*. OBS and Shutter still behave the same way; they don't work.
http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064

**Update 3:**
There seems to be a [report on the shutter launchpad regarding this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shutter/+bug/1061001). I couldn't find anything about OBS, though.

**Update 4:**
Looks like this is indeed a driver issue. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1080002

Comment: That must be related to circumstances particular to your system. I have Shutter without that problem. Maybe something to do with your graphics and GPU drivers?

Comment: Possibly. Tell me how to provide you with useful system data, and I will.

Comment: I am voting to close this because, at this time, I believe this is a known bug.

Comment: Still, there may be a resolution which we don't know of.