# Screenshots on Freya only capture background wallpaper

Tags: screenshot

Everytime I take a screenshot the result is only the background image.
Doesn't matter I do it via print key or open the tool itself. It does the same for opened windows when hitting <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Prt Sc</kbd> no matter if I'm fullscreen with that window or not.

Any ideas? :/

edit:

**sudo lshw -c video** gives

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff memory:f7e40000-f7e5ffff
```

and **fglrxinfo**

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.4.13374 Compatibility Profile Context 15.20.1013
```

Comment: Further informations would be helpful. Did you install any special graphic drivers?

Comment: Your problem sound very similar to [this one](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/385/22)

Comment: which information are needed? added some graphic card information

Comment: yeah, sounds nearly the same - he's also using a AMD card with proprietary drivers (although he has two cards on his system)

Comment: Proprietary Drivers cause that in my system with an AMD R7 card. Probably a Gala/Mutter bug.